# is there any way to iterate in 2-D array in CPLEX

Tags: cplex, opl

I want to model these [Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMrk7.png) in figure in CPLEX OPL, but CPLEX does not give opportunity to iterate in the multidimensional arrays. Cst and Tst are binary matrices, and the idea is to only sum for non zero elements.
How can I do this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I answered in community.ibm.com

```
range S=1..3;
range T=1..3;

int Cst[S][T] = [[0, 0 ,1],
         [1 ,0, 1],
         [0 ,1 ,0]];
         
dvar boolean x[S][T];

dvar int su; // sum all x such as Cst is 1

maximize su;
subject to
{
  su==sum(s in S,t in T:Cst[s][t]==1) x[s][t];
}
```

​

works fine and gives su=4